# Undefined Reference to _intel_fast_memcpy _intel_fast_memmove

Tags: c++, cmake, icc

I am compiled a library using intel c++ compiler. But now when I use in a program, I get the following errors. (This may be a duplicate question).

```
/usr/local/lib/libGE.a(Genotype.o): In function `std::char_traits<char>::length(char const*)':
/usr/include/c++/7.4.0/bits/char_traits.h:320: undefined reference to `__intel_sse2_strlen'
/usr/local/lib/libGE.a(Genotype.o): In function `int* std::__copy_move<true, true, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m<int>(int const*, int const*, int*)':
/usr/include/c++/7.4.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:368: undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memmove'
/usr/include/c++/7.4.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:368: undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memmove'
/usr/include/c++/7.4.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:368: undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memmove'
/usr/include/c++/7.4.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:368: undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memmove'
/usr/local/lib/libGE.a(Genotype.o): In function `int* std::__copy_move<false, true, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m<int>(int const*, int const*, int*)':
/usr/include/c++/7.4.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:368: undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memmove'
/usr/local/lib/libGE.a(Phenotype.o):/usr/include/c++/7.4.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:368: more undefined references to `_intel_fast_memmove' follow
/usr/local/lib/libGE.a(CFGrammar.o): In function `std::char_traits<char>::copy(char*, char const*, unsigned long)':
/usr/include/c++/7.4.0/bits/char_traits.h:350: undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memcpy'
/usr/include/c++/7.4.0/bits/char_traits.h:350: undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memcpy'
/usr/include/c++/7.4.0/bits/char_traits.h:350: undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memcpy'
/usr/include/c++/7.4.0/bits/char_traits.h:350: undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memcpy'
/usr/local/lib/libGE.a(CFGrammar.o): In function `std::char_traits<char>::length(char const*)':
```

Comment: Does [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/unresolved-external-symbol-_intel_sse2_strlen) help?

Comment: @PaulSanders No luck with that.

Comment: So you are linking against the relevant library?  Strange.

Comment: Which ones are the relevant ones?

Comment: According to the article, libirc.lib.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @PaulSanders I just noticed that the libirc.a library does not reside in the usual directory where libraries are installed; so I linked it using an absolute path in my CMakeLists.txt and it works now.